# Android 3.5 does not import widgets

Tags: java, android-studio

It might be a super simple question, but it is a huge issue for me as I am new to AS.

I updated latest version of AS (3.5), when I wanted to import widgets to assign to variables in XML layout, the AutoComplete doesn't come up, I attached the screen shoot to make it clear. I know I missed some parts when I updated.

Any help or suggestion will be highly appreciated it.

[image]

Comment: You basically declare at outside the class.

Comment: Why would you make a declaration outside your class and lay the complaints on android studio?

Comment: Thank you all, now I realised what I have done. SO SILLY

Answer (score 3):

You are declaring outside the class. You need to declare inside it.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //Inside the class
    private TextView textView;
```

Comment: Such A SILLYYYYYYY mistake I made. Thank you so much for your help dude.